# Integral of the log is less than the integral of the log of the average value

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, inequality

This is an interesting property that I came across while reading an old proof on this website. The poster didn't really explain it, so I thought I might ask. We suppose $u$ is a positive measure on some space $X$ and we have a measurable function $f:X\rightarrow(0,\infty)$. Then on some $E \subset X$ where $0<u(E)<\infty$ and $0<\int_Efdu<\infty$ we define the average value by $\hat{f}_E=\frac{1}{u(E)}\int_Efdu$. The statement then is
$$\int_E\log{f}du\leq\int_E\log{\hat{f}_E}du$$
I tried it out with a few functions and it is true, but I'm not sure why. I presume it has to do with the concavity of $\log{(\cdot)}$ and it will hold true for any other concave function. Anyone care to explain explain.

Comment: See Jensen's inequality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality.

Comment: But Jensen's inequality requires $u(E)=1$.

Comment: Right, I didn't intend my comment to be an answer, just a method for the OP to find some relevant information about the relationship between this inequality and convexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a new measure $v$ on $E$ as $v=\frac{u}{u(E)}$. Then $v(E)=1$ and $dv=\frac{du}{u(E)}$. Now apply Jensen's inequality to obtain the result.

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{E}\log \hat f\;du&=&(\log\hat f)\int_{E}du\\
&=&u(E)\log \hat f\\
&=&u(E)\log\left(\frac{1}{u(E)}\int_{E}f\;du\right)\\
&=&u(E)\log\left(\int_{E}f\;dv\right)\\
&\geq&u(E)\int_{E}\log f\;dv\\
&=&\int_{E}\log f\;du
\end{eqnarray}